# Attempt to read property "name" on null Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

i am creating a simple inventory system using laravel 9.I want to join the there tables in Laravel those are category and brand table and product.i have written the join queries.but i ran into the problem with **Attempt to read property "name" on null**
what i tried so far i attached code snippet below.

what i checked the error Error has point out of this line
**{{ $item->category->name }}**

**Product Model**

```
protected $table = 'products';

protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 
protected $fillable = ['barcode_no', 'productname', 'cat_id', 'brand_id', 'price'];


public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

**Category Model**

```
protected $table = 'categories';


    protected $primaryKey = 'id';


    protected $fillable = ['name', 'status'];


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'cat_id', 'id');
    }
```

**Brand Model**

```
protected $table = 'brands';


    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

 
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'status'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'brand_id', 'id');
   }
```

**Product view**

```
@foreach($products as $item)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->barcode_no }}</td>
       <td>{{ $item->productname }}</td>
       <td>{{ $item->category->name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $item->brand->name }}</td>
    </tr>
```

ProductController

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $perPage = 25;

        if (!empty($keyword)) {
            $products = Product::where('barcode_no', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('productname', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('cat_id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('brand_id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('price', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->latest()->paginate($perPage);
        } else {
            $products = Product::latest()->paginate($perPage);
        }

        return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

Comment: The error basically means that `$item->category` is null AND you can't get the `name` on a null. You can do something like `empty($item->category) ? null : $item->category->name`

Comment: so how to load instead of catid load as name

Comment: $item->category->name not loading

Comment: Have you tried this `empty($item->category) ? null : $item->category->name`

Comment: yes catname not shown up only brand name shown y

Comment: @abijega change relation to return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'cat_id'); in product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with naming convention `cat_id` in products table so need to change the relation like below by mentioning category id

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'cat_id');
}
```

It looks like one of the product might not have an assigned category. So check the null check in the blade template using [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional) helper.

```
<td>{{ optional($item->category)->name }}</td>
<td>{{ optional($item->brand)->name??null }}</td>
```

and in your controller, you can optimize code little bit using [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $perPage = 25;

            $products = Product::with(['category','brand'])->when(!empty($keyword),function ($query)use($keyword){
                $query->where('barcode_no', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere('productname', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere('cat_id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere('brand_id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere('price', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
            })->latest()->paginate($perPage);


        return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'));
}
```